# Use JDBC (eg Squirrel SQL) to query Cassandra with Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Cassandra cluster with a co-located Spark cluster, and I can run the usual Spark jobs by compiling them, copying them over, and using the ./spark-submit script. I wrote a small job that accepts SQL as a command-line argument, submits it to Spark as Spark SQL, Spark runs that SQL against Cassandra and writes the output to a csv file.

Now I feel like I'm going round in circles trying to figure out if it's possible to query Cassandra via Spark SQL directly in a JDBC connection (eg from Squirrel SQL). The Spark SQL documentation says

```
Connect through JDBC or ODBC.

A server mode provides industry standard JDBC and ODBC connectivity for
business intelligence tools.
```

The Spark SQL Programming Guide says

```
Spark SQL can also act as a distributed query engine using its JDBC/ODBC or
command-line interface. In this mode, end-users or applications can interact
with Spark SQL directly to run SQL queries, without the need to write any 
code.
```

So I can run the Thrift Server, and submit SQL to it. But what I can't figure out, is how do I get the Thrift Server to connect to Cassandra? Do I simply pop the Datastax Cassandra Connector on the Thrift Server classpath? How do I tell the Thrift Server the IP and Port of my Cassandra cluster? Has anyone done this already and can give me some pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure those properties in spark-default.conf file

```
spark.cassandra.connection.host    192.168.1.17,192.168.1.19,192.168.1.21
# if you configured security in you cassandra cluster
spark.cassandra.auth.username   smb
spark.cassandra.auth.password   bigdata@123
```

Start your thrift server with spark-cassandra-connector dependencies and mysql-connector dependencies with some port that you will connect via JDBC or Squirrel.

```
sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host 192.168.1.17 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port 10003 --jars <shade-jar>-0.0.1.jar --driver-class-path <shade-jar>-0.0.1.jar
```

For getting cassandra table run Spark-SQL queries like

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytable USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra OPTIONS (cluster 'BDI Cassandra', keyspace 'testks', table 'testtable');
```

Comment: The "USING" could be the missing link I couldn't figure out - I'll give it a go and see if it works!

Comment: With the Thrift server turned on, can I connect to it directly using JDBC UI eg Squirrel SQL? Do I need a specific client jar on my JDBC UI classpath in order to connect to the thrift server?

Comment: spark/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://192.168.1.14:10000

Comment: Sorry, I was travelling for most of December so have only just had a chance to try this out. Beeline connects perfectly! Adding the jars was annoying as there are a number of dependencies (cassandra-connector, guava, cassandra-core, etc) so I created a big shaded bundle with maven, and voila!

Comment: Now to see if I can connect to it from Squirrel SQL :)

Comment: Yes you can. Create one connection in Squirrel using all require jars for hive-jdbc.

Comment: Perfect - added hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar and hadoop-common-2.6.3.jar to my Squirrel driver and managed to connect. Thanks!

Comment: Is the temporary table a view over the cassandra table? What happens if new data is inserted into cassandra? Is this reflected in the 'temporary' thrift table as well?

Comment: Yes new data will also reflect in your table, its only a mapping between Spark and Cassandra. And it will reflect  in 'temporary' thrift table as well.

Comment: Tell me please: Does it mean that we may use cassandra instead of hive. So cassandra may be storage for data and additionally it may expose data for tableau for example. Is it possible to cache data from cassndra in memory ? (It is possible when it comes to hive).

Answer (score 1):

why don`t you use the spark-cassandra-connector and cassandra-driver-core? Just add the dependencies, specify the host address/login in your spark context and then you can read/write to cassandra using sql.

Comment: I have done this in a job jar, but I still need to use the spark-submit script to submit my SQL job onto spark, which requires command-line access. Is it possible to run SQL directly from a PC, connecting to Spark/Cassandra?